# How to Move UITableViewCell Image To Right

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swift3

I want to make the value of `UITableViewCell.imageView` to appear when run on the right instead of left. I also want the image to not be as big as the whole cell row height and be a bit smaller.

It looks like this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k00Dr.png)

And I want it to look like this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6a9Qb.png)

Thanks.

Comment: You can create your own custom TableViewCell , and implemented design as required.

Comment: We are not able to understand clarify your question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom UITableViewCell add proper constraints to the UIImageView and use multiplier in the constraint given to your UIImageView.